# A variant of Viviani's theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Consider an equilateral triangle $ABC$ of side $l$, and a point $P$ inside $ABC$.

The following picture represents a *proof without words* of the fact that, given any $P$, the sum of the segments $x,y,z$ is invariant for any $P$,  and $x+y+z=l$.

[image]

The segments $x,y,z$ are obtained by letting  three lines, each parallel to one of the sides, passing through the point $P$.

Similarly, the following picture 
shows that, given any $P$, also the sum of the lengths of the segments $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ is invariant, and such that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=l$.

[image]

The segments $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are obtained by carrying the shorter sides of the triangle $APC$ on its longest one.

> How can we map each $(x,y,z)$ tuple to each $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ tuple (and vice versa)?

NOTE: This post is the corrected version of a previous one, with similar title, that I deleted because of errors pointed out by clever and kind users. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you.  I understand the question now, though I don't know how to solve it.  +1 for the proof with words!

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for your help. I thought it was better to split the picture in two. However, the first proof without words is not mine (you can find it here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZWPtZjLGoE).

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TripolarCoordinates.html

Comment: Let $Y$ be foot of the perpendicular from $P$ to $\overline{AB}$. Then Pythagoras will give you $|PA|$ and $|PB|$. For instance, $$|PA|^2 = |AY|^2 + |PY|^2 = \left(x + \frac{1}{2}y\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}y\right)^2= x^2 + x y + y^2$$ Finding $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ is then straightforward. To reverse the process, note that $$|\triangle PAB| = \frac12|AB||PY|=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} y |AB|$$ You can use Heron's formula to determine $|\triangle PAB|$ from $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and then solve for $y$.

Comment: (Whoops. ... I wrote $B$s where I meant $C$s.)